# WatchKit:Delay when phone sends response to watch

Tags: ios, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I have a watchOS2 app which requires live updates. This is done through socket data in phone. When the phone gets the data, it posts it to the watch. But the problem is that there is a delay from phone to watch. I am using :

```
[WCSession defaultSession] updateApplicationContext:message error:error];
```

But still there is a few second delay.

I tried using `sendMessage` , but this too had a same problem. When I checked in Apple document it says data will be sent at "Opportune" time. Is there no workaround for this?

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html

Another link which says the same:

https://www.macstories.net/stories/watchos-2-review/2/

Comment: You won't get real-time updates on your watch. "WatchConnectivity saves battery life...". Many of Apple's decisions are meant to optimize the user's experience with the device. You could file a bug report with Apple, but if you expect an answer from SO why `sendMessage` might not be as responsive as you like, you'd really have to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using sendMessage from the watch for immediate updates.  For example, when you display the user interface elements on the watch and need the data, then request it from the phone.  This is fast (for reasonable amounts of data) because normally your watch app is active (giving it priority) and your phone app can be woken up to respond.  Although you may need to enable background processing on your iPhone app to support this.

I suspect the reason people find the application context updates to slow is because they are expected to be used when the watch app is not active.